# Authentication mechanisms for Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, authentication, windows-authentication

I would like to know what are all the possible ways we can use authentication mechanism in windows application ? Which is the best and optimized way in multi server scenario (I mean multi tier).

Also please give me link of how to use LDAP for authentication (If I am not wrong).

I am looking for something like Windows/Forms/Passport which exists for ASP.NET

Thanks in advance. It will be great if you can make me understand with a small possible code example too....

Comment: Let me refer you here: [What Kind of questions should I _not_ ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Thank you, its a great attitude of you and help. :) I appreciate and wish you, I will take a look at this link. :) Cheers

Comment: not a problem Divine, also I work with ActiveDirectory and LDAP Currently ..when you get to that portion of doing Authentication based on Domain login let me know and I can assist you with code as well, currently we use it in our Enterprise Web Applications doing My Mobility

Comment: @DJKRAZE: :) Thank you that soothes me so much. I am currently in learning phase, I am new to these programming :(... Anyway surely will let you know. Thank you again :)

Comment: We all have to start somewhere best thing to do is to not panic or become overwhelmed once you get the basics down.. you will become a Guru in no time..:)
Divine hang in there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divine here is an awesome example plus code that you can download in how to create / test basic LDAP User, Password and Domain download the code make the changes to fit your environment and step through the code via the Debugger and learn what each piece is doing. You should be able to get the hang of this rather quickly.

[Authentication against Active Directory and Edirectory via LDAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5969/Authentication-against-Active-Directory-and-Edirec)

Comment: Oh that looks like kind of exactly what I am looking for, thank you so much, I will read this link now itself and understand :) I appreciate your help greatly, thank you again :)

Comment: Actually I was asked about this question in Microsoft Interview few days back, I couldn't answer about LADP. And then my bad, I didn't come and read. Today I missed doing well in Goldman Sachs interview on the same question :( I couldn't say them what methods I can authenticate an application user in Winform apps (As I was not part of doing that in applications I worked but my Architect :( )..I told the same to them but I tried saying atleast LDAP and then they asked me in detail, I couldn't answer any.

Comment: Two big giants I lost (One Microsoft, where I cleared 1 round and in 2nd round I was lost in LDAP/Active Directory questions) ( I had 2 rounds of interview with Goldman sachs today, and don't know the feedback, but I didn't do well as many small questions, I didn't answer well lol ). So I thought to study about these now ;)

Comment: Goldman Sachs what part of the country are you interviewing for that position? I use to be a senior developer for JPMorgan Chase when they were BankOne as well..LOL there a Ton of IT jobs here in Dallas Texas area..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15081/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-divine)

Comment: Sure lets continue in chat, I am currently not in Linkedin